# Is it possible to use a slice of type struct with sqlx.In

Tags: go, sqlx

Is it possible to use a slice of type struct with [sqlx.In](https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries) and [sqlx.Rebind](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Tx.Rebind) in Golang?

For example,

```
type param struct {
    ID        string `db:"id"`
    FirstName string `db:"first_name"`
    Surname   string `db:"surname"`
}

params := []param{
    {
        ID:        "1",
        FirstName: "Bob",
        Surname:   "Smith",
    },
    {
        ID:        "2",
        FirstName: "Jane",
        Surname:   "Smith",
    },
}

query, args, err := sqlx.In("INSERT INTO user (id, first_name, surname) VALUES (?)", params)
// INSERT INTO user (id, first_name, surname) VALUES (?, ?)

query = pg.Rebind(query)
// INSERT INTO user (id, first_name, surname) VALUES ($1, $2)

err := pg.Exec(query, args...)
// sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type datastore.param, a struct
```

The above code returns the error as it is expanding the bindvar to the length of the slice `params` slice but not the fields of the values in the slice.

```
sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type datastore.param, a struct
```

Is it possible to expand the fields to something like

```
INSERT INTO user (id, first_name, surname) VALUES ($1, $2, $3), ($4, $5, $6)
```

Comment: I don't have any real experience with `sqlx`, but according to the docs, `In expands slice values in args, returning the modified query string and a new arg list that can be executed by a database.`  That reads to me as if you can pass in a series of slices, rather than structs - so something like `sqlx.In("<query>", []string{"id1","fn1","sn1"}, []string{"id2","fn2","sn2"}) sounds like it _might_ work to do what you're after.  But I could also be wildly off base here.

Answer (score 0):

[Squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel) query builder has saved me most of the hassle on dynamic queries and multi-value inserts

check their example for your case, it does exactly what you want and the syntax is clear:

```
sql, args, err := sq.
Insert("users").Columns("name", "age").
Values("moe", 13).Values("larry", sq.Expr("? + 5", 12)).
ToSql()

sql == "INSERT INTO users (name,age) VALUES (?,?),(?,? + 5)"
```